# mutableArrayValueForKey: countOf<Key> not being called, countOfSongs

Tags: swift, key-value-coding

My exact question is here:

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/236041-kvc-array-proxy-objects.html#236058

```
I'm trying to understand how the proxy object which is returned from
mutableArrayValueForKey: works and I've hit a bit of a wall.  I get
what the proxy is and why it exists.  I have a test app which allows
me to do things to/with the collection it represents and it all works
fine.  The problem is that when I try to implement some of the methods
mentioned in the developer docs under the "Key-Value Coding Accessor
Methods" section.  There are some methods there which if implemented
in the hosting object (i.e. the original recipient of the
mutableArrayValueForKey: call) are to be called by the proxy when the
proxy is asked to do various things.  The hitch is that in my test app
I can't get the -countOf<key> or -objectIn<key>AtIndex methods to be
invoked.
In reading through the docs, it seems that a number of methods need
to be implemented before any of these (dare I call them 'proxy
methods'?) are called.  I implemented a whole slew of them - including
a number that shouldn't need to be - and ended up with this set: (The
test app is based on a Playlist->Songs->Song model where "songs" is
the NSMutableArray which lives in the Playlist class in which I'm
interested in getting a count of its member songs.)

- (unsigned int)countOfSongs;
- (Song *)objectInSongsAtIndex:(unsigned int)index;
- (NSArray *)songsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)getSongs:(Song **)buffer range:(NSRange)inRange;
- (void)insertObject:(Song *)newSong inSongsAtIndex:(unsigned int)idx;
- (void)removeObjectFromSongsAtIndex:(unsigned int)idx;

     Even simple test code like this fails:

Playlist *myPlaylist = [[[Playlist alloc] init] autorelease];
id arrayProxy = [myPlaylist mutableArrayValueForKey:@"songs"];
[arrayProxy insertObject:[[[Song alloc] initWithName:@"test" andLength:
10] autorelease] atIndex:0];
unsigned int theCount = [arrayProxy count];

I've got all the properties defined, all the methods written, etc.
Yet when I call [arrayProxy count] my countOfSongs method in the
Playlist class isn't touched.  The right answer is returned, but it's
apparently coming from the runtime going to the array directly and
getting the answer via NSArray's count method.
Oddly enough, when I do the insertObject call in line #3 the
insertObject:inSongsAtIndex: method IS called... so some of this stuff
works as I believe it is supposed to.  Unfortunately it's the other
stuff that's driving me nuts.  I've been working on this one for a
couple of days now and have tried everything I could come up with -
including some really silly, paranoid stuff - and have made no progress.
Can anybody help me with a suggestion as to what I might be doing
wrong or what I'm missing?
Thanks!
```

And the answer there--although it seemed to help the op--does nothing to shed any light on the problem for me.

Here is my playground code:

```
import Cocoa

"hello"

class Song {
    dynamic var title = "Hello"
}

"hello"


class PlayList: NSObject {

    /*dynamic*/ var songs = NSMutableArray()
    //private var theSongs = NSMutableArray()

    //var countOfSongs: Int = 100

    func countOfSongs() -> Int {
        println("count of songs")

        return 100
        //return theSongs.count + 100
    }

    func objectInSongsAtIndex(i: Int) -> AnyObject? {
        println("getter")
        return songs[i]
        //return theSongs[i]
    }


    func insertObject(song:AnyObject, inSongsAtIndex index:Int) {
        println("insert")
        songs[index] = song as! Song
        //theSongs[index] = song as! Song
    }

    func removeObjectFromSongsAtIndex(index:Int) {
        println("remove")
        songs.removeObjectAtIndex(index)
        //theSongs.removeObjectAtIndex(index)

    }

}



"hello"

var playlist = PlayList()

"hello"

let arrayProxy = playlist.mutableArrayValueForKey("songs")

"hello"

arrayProxy.addObject(Song())  //successfully calls proxy method => outputs "insert"
arrayProxy.removeObjectAtIndex(0)  //successfully calls proxy method => outputs "remove"
arrayProxy.count   //=> 0  ???
```

What changes do I need to make to my code so that the countOfSongs property or method is called when I write:

```
arrayProxy.count
```

Comment: Renaming the property `songs` to `theSongs` (as in your commented-out code) should solve the issue.

Comment: @MartinR, Then the line: `let arrayProxy = playlist.mutableArrayValueForKey("songs")`fails--presumably because there is no property named songs. And that is what I don't get about the answer at the link.

Comment: Well, I tried it. I just renamed "songs" to "theSongs", and it compiled and worked as expected. I have added the modified code to the answer below, so you can compare it with yours.

Comment: @MartinR,  Compiled??  I copy and pasted your code in a playground--and it doesn't work, but your code does work in a project.  Great!  I just wasted hours on this problem.  I'll never use a playground again.  Can you confirm that your code does not work in a playground?  I'm using Xcode 6.3.2

Comment: It crashes in a Playground (Xcode 6.4), but with `*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array`. I assume that Xcode wants to display the proxy object. That fails because the `thesongs` array is empty.

Comment: @MartinR, I don't get any error message--instead all the output for all the lines gets grayed out, telling me something went wrong.  Is there some setting to show errors?

Comment: Did you try "View -> Assistant Editor -> Show Assistant Editor ..." ? – But I always use compiled projects when I search for compiler errors, that is much easier.

Comment: @MartinR, Thanks for the tip.  On another note: In a project, I can set the array like this:  `private var theSongs = [Song(), Song()]`.  Previously, I had tried using an empty Swift array: [], but an error message somewhere told me that the empty initialization created an NSArray--which is immutable.  I guess in Swift, if you populate the array when initializing, you get an NSMutableArray.  In any case, the code with the populated array would not work in a playground either--it still produces an index out of range error.

Comment: @MartinR, Okay, I figured out what was causing the playground error: I'm returning 100 for the countOfSongs, and when the playground tries to output the string representation of the array, it loops over the array to get the values(or maybe that happens in the array's description method) and the playground uses countOfSongs as the length of the array, and obviously the array doesn't have indexes that go up to 100, hence the out of bounds error.

Comment: And about this:  *`private var theSongs = [Song(), Song()]`  Previously, I had tried using an empty Swift array: [], but an error message somewhere told me that the empty initialization created an NSArray--which is immutable.*  It turns out I wrote: `private var theSongs = []` and Swift can't infer the type, so Swift apparently defaulted to type NSArray.  If I write `private var theSongs: [Song] = []`, then theSongs is initialized with an NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the referenced article
http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/236041-kvc-array-proxy-objects.html#236058:

> The documentation about accessor search order shows that it will
>   prefer a method named `-<key>` over the corresponding `-countOf<Key>` and
>   `- objectIn<Key>AtIndex:` methods.

which means that

```
let arrayProxy = playlist.mutableArrayValueForKey("songs")
let cnt = arrayProxy.count
```

accesses the "songs" property of `Playlist` directly, if there is such
a property.

If you rename the property then it works as you expected:

```
class Song {
    dynamic var title = "Hello"
}

class PlayList: NSObject {

    var thesongs = NSMutableArray()

    func countOfSongs() -> Int {
        println("count of songs")
        return 100
    }

    func objectInSongsAtIndex(i: Int) -> AnyObject? {
        println("getter")
        return thesongs[i]
    }

    func insertObject(song:AnyObject, inSongsAtIndex index:Int) {
        println("insert")
        thesongs[index] = song as! Song
    }

    func removeObjectFromSongsAtIndex(index:Int) {
        println("remove")
        thesongs.removeObjectAtIndex(index)
    }
}

var playlist = PlayList()
let arrayProxy = playlist.mutableArrayValueForKey("songs")
let cnt = arrayProxy.count  
println(cnt)
```

Output:

```
count of songs
100
```

Answer (score 1):

For future searchers, here is a full example exercising all the methods in an OSX>Application>Command Line Tool (I checked Swift for the language):

```
import Foundation

class Song {
    var title = "Hello"
}

class PlayList: NSObject {

    private var array: [Song] = []

    func countOfSongs() -> Int {
        println("countOfSongs() called")
        return array.count
    }

    /*
    //This also works:
    var countOfSongs: Int {
        println("countOfSongs property was accessed")
        return array.count
    }
    */


    func objectInSongsAtIndex(index: Int) -> AnyObject? {
        println("getter called")
        return array[index]
    }

    func insertObject(song:AnyObject, inSongsAtIndex index:Int) {
        println("inserting at index \(index)")
        array.insert(song as! Song, atIndex: index)
    }

    func removeObjectFromSongsAtIndex(index:Int) {
        println("removing at index \(index)")
        array.removeAtIndex(index)
    }

}


var playlist = PlayList()
let arrayProxy = playlist.mutableArrayValueForKey("songs")
arrayProxy.addObject(Song())

println(arrayProxy.count)

arrayProxy.objectAtIndex(0)
arrayProxy.removeObjectAtIndex(0)

println(arrayProxy.count)


var playlist = PlayList()
let arrayProxy = playlist.mutableArrayValueForKey("songs")

arrayProxy.addObject(Song())
println(arrayProxy.count)
arrayProxy.removeObjectAtIndex(0)

println(arrayProxy.count)

--output:--
countOfSongs() called
inserting at index 0
countOfSongs() called
1
getter called
removing at index 0
countOfSongs() called
0
```

No more playgrounds for me!